# didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not invoked to UIButton of cellForRowAtIndex

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I know that there are many duplicates here regarding this question but my requirement is that I added 2 UIButtons on one cell and both the buttons will open two different views. If I set the property userInteractionEnabled to YES, then it will not pic the 'finalID' from didSelectRowAtIndexPath from the below code.

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

    if(tableView == self.tableViewProject){
        static NSString *cellId = @"attachmentCellId";
        attachmentCell *cell = (attachmentCell *)[self.tableViewProject dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
        if(!cell)
        {
            if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"attachmentCell" owner:self options:Nil];
                for(id object in nib)
                {
                    if([object isKindOfClass:[attachmentCell class]])
                    {
                        cell = (attachmentCell *)object;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                UIButton *button;
                button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(162, 0, 75, 53)];
                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
//button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

                UIButton *buttonAttach = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(245, 0, 75, 53)];
                [buttonAttach addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAttachClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


                buttonAttach.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
//buttonAttach.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:buttonAttach];

                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
                SaveAttachment *attach = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                cell.name.text = attach.name;
                cell.list.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", attach.list];
                cell.attachment.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", attach.attachment];
                cell.date.text = attach.date;
            }
    return cell;
    }
```

And my DidSelectRowAtIndexPath is

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSLog(@"Array == %@", anotherTempArray);

        NSString *finalId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [anotherTempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"final id for selected row = %@", finalId);
        NSUserDefaults *defaultForFinalId = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *setFinalId = finalId;
        [defaultForFinalId setObject:setFinalId forKey:@"SETFINALID"];

    if(tableView == self.tableViewProject)
    {

        [self buttonClicked];
        //[self viewDidLoadForList];

    }
    if(tableView == self.tableViewAttachmentList)
    {


        [self buttonAttachClicked];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to call the selector of `UIButton` inside cell, then what you dont need to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

What you did was correct upto adding handler to `UIButton`. Now, remove your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` code to button's click handler. Here is how you can get indexPath from the button click handler.

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender.superview.superview; //Since you are adding to cell.contentView, navigate two levels to get cell object
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    // Now you can do the code you put in didSelectRow here.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good job men.
I have some changes with swift 3.
So working awesome !

Answer (score 1):

change your code for button selector

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //add colon in selector buttonClicked


[buttonAttach addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAttachClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //add colon in selector buttonAttachClicked
```

Comment: methods don't have arguments suhit

Comment: when you call the method on the button, you need to pass the reference of that button to the method and can check tag or button title to verify.

Comment: what is self.tableViewProject and self.tableViewAttachmentList? are you using two tableview outlets

Answer (score 1):

If U use buttons than U don't need to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Set tags on buttons to match indexPath.row of the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath... This way when U press the button in buttonAttachClicked or buttonClicked just check the senders tag and pull that cell from the UITableView

Use this code for cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if(tableView == self.tableViewProject){
    static NSString *cellId = @"attachmentCellId";
    attachmentCell *cell = (attachmentCell *)[self.tableViewProject dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if(!cell)
    {
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"attachmentCell" owner:self options:Nil];
            for(id object in nib)
            {
                if([object isKindOfClass:[attachmentCell class]])
                {
                    cell = (attachmentCell *)object;
                    break;
                }

            }

            cell.button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(162, 0, 75, 53)];
            [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.button];

            cell.buttonAttach = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(245, 0, 75, 53)];
            [cell.buttonAttach addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAttachClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.buttonAttach];

            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
SaveAttachment *attach = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.name.text = attach.name;
cell.list.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", attach.list];
cell.attachment.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", attach.attachment];
cell.date.text = attach.date;        
[cell.button setTag:indexPath.row];
[cell.buttonAttach setTag:indexPath.row];            

return cell;
}
```

Comment: so how do put the tags? button.tag = indexpath.row? ?

Comment: I have edited my answer... And then U define the button methods like -(void)buttonAttachClicked:(id)sender, and the otherone just like that one

Comment: Ok one more thing, U need your buttons to be objects of attachmentCell so that U can have reference to them, then U just add cell. before button and buttonAttach

Comment: cell.button will throw a compile time error as attachmentCell does not have a button. We a make a button programmatically here

Comment: Put it in a nib and outlet to it or add it programatically, it doesn't matter how U do it, U just need the reference cause when using reusable cells U will use the same button to present multiple tags and  if U don't have an reference on the cells button you wont be able to determent which record to pull from array... U have another mistake

Comment: The block where U assign values to cell properties musn't be in if(cell == nil) block