# didSelectRowAtIndexpath not triggered for button inside a tableview cell Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a button inside a tableview cell (as shown in the below image), when I click the button,

> didSelectRowAt indexpath

is not being triggered, could some one please suggest how I could do this ?

**Please note:**
I am performing a set of actions on click of the button, in addition I would also like

> didselectRowAt indexPath

to be triggered.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 print("Table view cell has been clicked")   
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you assign theTableView delegate to the class you are putting the code in? You should be working with UITableViewDelegate

Comment: what action is the button performing?  It could call the `didselectRowAt indexPath` directly (or to be more correct, call some other function that is called by `didselectRowAt indexPath` and by the button's own method).  Take a look at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117163/didselectrowatindexpath-is-not-invoked-to-uibutton-of-cellforrowatindex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not invoked to UIButton of cellForRowAtIndex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117163/didselectrowatindexpath-is-not-invoked-to-uibutton-of-cellforrowatindex)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429652/detecting-uibutton-pressed-in-tableview-swift-best-practices Swift alternative if you don't know how to add an action to an UIButton.

Comment: [SEE THIS LINK for better under standing please go through that question in link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42364716/6818278)

Comment: Try connecting the button action to your subclassed UITableViewCell, inside that action call self.setSelected...

Answer (score 3):

When you have multiple views in the cell they may receive the touch event and not the "cell" so didSelectRowAt will not be triggered. In that case add `view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` to each view, label or button.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding button or gesture on `UITableViewCell` , `didselectRowAt indexPath` not invoked . You can add button on remaining UI `UITableViewCell` than clear color apply on button . User didn't show button and you can perform `didselectRowAt indexPath` method task . If you wanna `indexpath` in button method code give below.

```
 func btnChildDropDown(sender:UIButton)
    {
       let cell = sender.superview?.superview as! ChildAgeTableViewCell
       let indexPath = self.tblViewAddRooms.indexPath(for: cell)

    }
```

Comment: Very nice answer, we find the section as well as index in multi sections table view. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put the outlet to the button inside a custom cell class.  Then set tag and add selector for button in cellForItemAt.  This example is for colletionView just change to suit tableView.

If you want the button in each cell this is how you have to do it.  Adding a static button to a single cell won't call didSelectItemAt because your tapping a button that doesn't have reference to a reusable cells indexPath.

This way we send the button.tag tot he function so we know which cell the button is related to.

```
class MyClassViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    .... // Stuff

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    ....// Create Cell

    cell.deleteCellButton.tag = indexPath.item
    cell.deleteCellButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyClassViewController.deleteCellButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}

func deleteCellButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

     ... // Stuff

      print("Selector called")
}
}
```

Comment: Do not use the index path as a tag. It fails under many situations.

Comment: I read apple doesn't want you using it anymore.  Whats the solution then? as this seems to be the way most people construct nested table views / collection views?

Comment: There are plenty of questions covering this so I won't provide too many details. But basically, if you need to determine the index path of a button in the button's action method, you calculate it based on the button's frame relative to the table view using the methods of the `UITableView` class.

Comment: @WanderingScouse, @rmaddy, I understand that you can attach a function to a button as shown above, but how do you activate the delegate methods like `didSelectRowAt indexPath`

Comment: @user44776 You don't. Simply have the button handler and the delegate method both call a common method.

Comment: @rmaddy, As I want to increase the cell height on button click, could I replicate `heightForRowAt IndexPath` inside IBAction of button ?